# TinyDB search with a variable in query

Tags: python, python-3.x, tinydb

I'm trying to execute a directory list and make a search by filename in a TinyDb database, like below:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
import os, fnmatch

db = TinyDB('DB_links_filenames.json')

User = Query()

def getFieldData(campo,nome):
    results = db.search(User.file == nome )
    result = [r[campo] for r in results]
    return result


listOfFiles = os.listdir('/home/files')
pattern = "*.mp4"
for entry in listOfFiles:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
            print(getFieldData('url',entry))
```

The problem is the filename goes to the function as expected, but appears to be blank in `db.search...`, I've tried several methods like:`%nome or [nome] or (nome)` in order to add the variable to search query but no sucess, the result is always the same `[]`.

If the name of file is inserted direct to the query `db.search(User.file == 'filename' )` everything works normally.

Any suggestion what could be?

Comment: use `print(nome)` to see what value you have in this variable in function. Maybe you  have something different then you expect.

Comment: @furas, if I use print(nome) the value is correct. Tested on the function too, and received the right value too.

Comment: maybe there is no result in database for this value.

Comment: @furas, yes the value exists, if I type the value in the place of the variable it's find normally

Comment: we can't resolve it without your data and disk to see differences in names. It can be even small difference like space in name or uppercase/lowercase name, name with and without extension.

Comment: you can only check `print( nome == 'filename'` ) to see if names of disk are really the same as name which you put manually.

Comment: I did this test and they are, I guess that the problem is when the var is passed to command (maybe string when needs to be object?)